# How to say that an online demo is interactive in 2-3 words?

Tags: website-design, web-app, user-behavior, copywriting

Basically, they can play around with the app, to get a feel for it in a advance. The target audience is business owners who may or may not (likely not) be technologically inclined.

**Demo** implies that they might just be watching something (a demonstration).

**Interactive Demo** feels like it might be a bit too techie for the crowd.

**Test** can imply that the app is in beta and we're asking them to test it.

**Test Drive** sounds a little too informal and I don't much like it, but so far seems to be the least problematic choice.

What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: "interactive online demo" ;)

Comment: Most users do not read. Just make sure that the demo's interactivity is easy to discover.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Try it yourself" sounds like a phrase that could fit your bill. "Try it", "Try yourself" could also be used, or "it" could be replaced by the name of the app.

Comment: As "it" is such a short word you could have "Try it for yourself" and not break the length limit :)

Comment: Or variants using a noun: trial e.g. Body text: .. A free trial account ... Button text: try it now

Comment: Why not just 'Try Demo'?

Answer (score 8):

Why 2-3 words?  Sacrificing clarity for the sake of brevity is rarely a good idea.

Ask your customers which is clearer to them.  It's not going to be a lot of work and you will get real data to base your decision on.

That said, I would opt for **test drive** as it seems the clearest to me.  Generally informal software that speaks more like a human is more usable, so if it comes across as informal, then great!

Answer (score 5):

Because your users are not primarily technical, avoiding any techie description is important ( and because they are senior business people, it can make them feel uncomfortable, and so start them off with a negative perspective ).

Personally, I like test drive. They will be used to the concept, and ( if they regularly buy new cars ) will probably be excited by the prospect. TBH, if they are male, it will probably appeal!

So a) go with a totally non-techie term and b) make it sound like the experience will be enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

How about use what the software industry already use... **Beta**

Even then you could be more specific; public beta, open beta, closed beta, beta release etc

or instead how about preview, prototype, technical preview

Comment: I can think of a lot of users, and even some technical people, who would be confused by seeing the technical term "beta" being used in this context. I think other posters are right in saying the best choices in this instance are non-technical.

Comment: Also, "Beta" to me does not imply "demo"; rather, it makes a statement about the readiness of the application for release into the market—whatever the scope or limit of its functionality may be.